# Ionic 2 and Meteor facebook (social) authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, meteor, ionic2, meteor-accounts

I'm developing an Ionic v2 app with a Meteor backend (Ionic CLI). Basically like:  https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup. Basic username/password authentication works fine with the accounts-base-client-side and accounts-password-client-side packages. However, I'd like to authenticate with Facebook and other social login providers. Here it becomes kind of tricky.

Ionic offers a nice native Facebook authentication through Ionic Cloud services. See: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework. But how would this integrate with the Meteor Account authentication?